# gitlab docker compose not available

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-compose

I got the docker gitlab for testing on mac but I can't access the UI.

```
$ docker pull sameersbn/gitlab:8.7.3
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Running `docker exec -i -t dockersandbox_gitlab_1 netstat -tulpn` gives

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address        State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      453/nginx -g daemon
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      455/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      453/nginx -g daemon
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      455/sshd
```

Running `docker port dockersandbox_gitlab_1` gives me:

```
22/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:10022
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:10080
```

Comment: What is the content of your compose file? And remember you need to use `192.168.99.100` to access docker containers on Windows/Mac

Comment: `192.168.99.100` did the trick, I was trying on `localhost` instead. Do you want to write that as an answer so I can accept it?